# why can't I defne the function first?

Tags: javascript

```
"use strict";
var primaryJS = {
    getCommon : function(name){
        var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml.open('get',"./common/"+name+".html",true);
        xml.onreadyststechange=function(){
            if(xml.readyState==4&&(xml.status==200||xml.status==304)){
                var fill = xml.responseText;
                document.getElementById('common-'+name).innerHTML=fill;
            }
        }
        xml.send();
    }
}
+function(){
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var js = [];
    var css = [];
    css[0] = document.createElement('link');
    css[0].href = "./css/index.css";
    js[0] = document.createElement('script');
    js[0].src="./js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js";
    for(var min = 0;min<js.length;min++){
        js[min].type="text/javascript";
        frag.appendChild(js[min]);
    }
    for(var min = 0;min<css.length;min++){
        css[min].rel="stylesheet";
        frag.appendChild(css[min]);
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(frag);
    window.addEventListener('load',function(){
        primaryJS.getCommon('head');
        primaryJS.getCommon('foot');
    },false);
}()
```

I run this js in the tag "<head>" 
and the console shows that "primaryJS.getCommon is not a function",(chrome,win10x64)
but when i move the "var primaryJS = {}" after "+function(){}()";
just like this.

```
"use strict";
+function(){
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var js = [];
    var css = [];
    css[0] = document.createElement('link');
    css[0].href = "./css/index.css";
    js[0] = document.createElement('script');
    js[0].src="./js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js";
    for(var min = 0;min<js.length;min++){
        js[min].type="text/javascript";
        frag.appendChild(js[min]);
    }
    for(var min = 0;min<css.length;min++){
        css[min].rel="stylesheet";
        frag.appendChild(css[min]);
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(frag);
    window.addEventListener('load',function(){
        primaryJS.getCommon('head');
        primaryJS.getCommon('foot');
    },false);
}()
var primaryJS = {
    getCommon : function(name){
        var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml.open('get',"./common/"+name+".html",true);
        xml.onreadyststechange=function(){
            if(xml.readyState==4&&(xml.status==200||xml.status==304)){
                var fill = xml.responseText;
                document.getElementById('common-'+name).innerHTML=fill;
            }
        }
        xml.send();
    }
}
```

it runs normally.
I want to know why and is it effective to all browsers?
//last time the firefox shows a mistake just like "the function is not defined" when I try to define a function after i use it.

Comment: besides the more correct answers below, you can use `~` or `!` in place of `+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because you forgot an `;` after `primaryJS` declaration and because you put a `+` before your anonymous function. So in the first example `primaryJS` is initialized to an object + a function. You can ommit `;` when it's not ambiguous, my advice would be to always write them.

```
var primaryJS = {
    getCommon : function(name){
        var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml.open('get',"./common/"+name+".html",true);
        xml.onreadyststechange=function(){
            if(xml.readyState==4&&(xml.status==200||xml.status==304)){
                var fill = xml.responseText;
                document.getElementById('common-'+name).innerHTML=fill;
            }
        }
        xml.send();
    }
}; // <<<< here
```

Same thing for the function

```
function(){
    ...
}();
```

Why you put + before your function anyway? It doesn't return anything.

Comment: thanks,i use "+" because of the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (";"+function(){}()" is the same as "(function(){})()"